# How to get all the HTML of a scrolling website?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, urllib

I've been trying to get the HTML of some websites and I couldn't get the ones who have dynamic scrolling, for example [this site](http://shop.mango.com/ES/m/mujer/prendas/camisas/?m=familia&v=14) or [this site](http://www2.hm.com/es_es/mujer/compra-por-producto/chaquetas-y-abrigos.html)

In the first one you have a set of products and while you go down products go appearing, with the same link.

In the second you have 30 and +30 products for each scroll you make down, and link goes changing.

And when I do:

```
htmltext= urllib.urlopen(current_url).read()
```

In that `htmltext` I only find the first set of products, for example 30 of the total 134, and I want them all.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe it is called lazy loading, not dynamic scrolling. Try searching this site for "scraping dynamic webpages with Python"

Comment: Without visiting the pages, I suspect the content is loaded with JavaScript. Take a look at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) for scraping these types of pages.

Comment: I keep getting only the ones you see first without scrolling with Selenium , tried html = driver.page_source and links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")